# Where can I buy some ETH Testnet tokens?

Tags: blockchain, dapp-development, testnets, goerli, sepolia

we are building a project and are running out of testnet ETH testnet, we have a huge userbase and it needs more testnet Goerli ETH. If you have any suggestions, please, let me know here in the comments. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

1. https://goerlifaucet.com/
   This link gives 0.5 ETH per day once you have logged in with Alchemy account
2. https://goerli-faucet.pk910.de/
   Also, you can mine the test ETH to get 1.25 ETH at a once, but it might take some time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good faucet to get some Goerli Test-ETH, but make sure to use a system with good configuration, since it will use PoW to give you ETH.

https://goerli-faucet.pk910.de/

Answer (score 0):

theres a few websites and discord/telegram groups that offer testnets. But
i suggest Alchemy Goerli Testnet or You can try : https://faucetlink.to/goerli